# Натуральный логарифм числа

Tags: c++

Какая функция вычисляет натуральный логарифм числа в C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Функции вычисления [логарифма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC):

- [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) — [натуральный логарифм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC)
- [`std::log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10) — [десятичный логарифм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC)
- [`std::log2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) — [двоичный логарифм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC)
- [`std::log1p`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) — натуральный логарифм числа `1 + x`

  `log1p(x)` более точное чем `log(1 + x)` при маленьких `x`