# Как взять логарифм по основанию e?

Tags: c++

Как в C++ взять логарифм по основанию e?

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Натуральный логарифм числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776561). Также может быть полезен: [Логарифм в С++ по основанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1154845).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Натуральный логарифм числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776561/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стандартный подходит [std::log](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) ?

**upd**

теперь и с примером.

Добавляем вверху в список include строку `#include <cmath>`.

в нужном месте используем

```
double x = 10.0;
double lx = std::log(x); // посчитали
std::cout << "log(x) = " << lx << '\n'; // распечатали "log(x) = 2.30259"
```

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста немного не понимаю как

Comment: @MityaFara по ссылке есть пример

Answer (score 2):

Использовать функцию std::log из библиотеки cmath.